# Parse JSON for first instance of repeated data field in Java with org.JSON

Tags: java, json, parsing, org.json

I'm trying to parse the first instance of "actualEPS" from the following JSON file:

```
   {"symbol":"AAPL","earnings":[{"actualEPS":2.34,"consensusEPS":2.17,"estimatedEPS":2.17,"announceTime":"AMC","numberOfEstimates":10,"EPSSurpriseDollar":0.17,"EPSReportDate":"2018-07-31","fiscalPeriod":"Q3 2018","fiscalEndDate":"2018-06-30","yearAgo":1.67,"yearAgoChangePercent":0.40119760479041916,"estimatedChangePercent":0.29940119760479045,"symbolId":11},{"actualEPS":2.73,"consensusEPS":2.69,...}
```

Here is the method currently. I know I'm getting data from the target as I can Sysout the String "inputLine" and see the full file. I'm having trouble parsing from that point. I have installed and imported the org.JSON library.

```
    public static void getData(String s) throws Exception {
    String urlBase = new String(theWebSiteImGettingDataFrom)
    URL targetURL = new URL(urlBase);
    URLConnection yc = targetURL.openConnection();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(
                            yc.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) { 

        System.out.println(inputLine);
    } // end while

    in.close();

    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(inputLine);
    double eps = obj.getJSONObject("earnings").getDouble("actualEPS");

    System.out.println("This is the first instance of EPS: " + eps);

} // end getData method
```

I'm getting a Null Pointer Exception in the stack trace:

```
    at org.json.JSONTokener.<init>(JSONTokener.java:94)
at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:357)
at code.URLConnectionReader.getData(URLConnectionReader.java:39)
```

How do I parse the data for the first instance of "actualEPS" and only the first instance?

**EDIT**

```
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(inputLine);
    JSONArray earningsArray = obj.getJSONArray("earnings");
    JSONObject firstEPS = earningsArray.getJSONObject(0);
    double eps = firstEPS.getDouble("actualEPS");

    System.out.println("This is the first instance of EPS: " + eps);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as I have no idea how big your json is and as you only want to parse a specific part of the json itself, I would recommend you to use **JsonReader.class** instead of **JsonObject.class**.

Short difference:

- JsonObject parses the whole json into RAM and needs to be smaller than 1 MB.
- JsonReader uses a streaming approach, which allows you to handle big jsons more efficiently.

---

Secondly, if you know that you ALWAYS just need the first instance of your json you could simply shorten your jsonString itself before parsing it (e.g. `substring`, etc.).

---

Now to your code:

> public static void getData(String s) throws Exception {
>       String urlBase = new String(theWebSiteImGettingDataFrom)**;** // Semicolon!
>       URL targetURL = new URL(urlBase);
>       URLConnection yc = targetURL.openConnection();
>       BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
>                               new InputStreamReader(
>                               yc.getInputStream()));
>       String inputLine;
>
> ```
> while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) { 
>
>     System.out.println(inputLine);
> } // end while
>
> in.close();
>
> System.out.println("My json: "+inputLine); //TODO: What is your output here?  
>
> JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(inputLine);
> double eps = obj.getJSONObject("earnings").getDouble("actualEPS");
>
> System.out.println("This is the first instance of EPS: " + eps);
> ```
>
> } // end getData method

Please comment, as I can't tell if you get the json from your server.

---

**EDIT:**
Your error is in this line:

```
double eps = obj.getJSONObject("earnings").getDouble("actualEPS");
```

In short it should be like this:

```
double eps = obj.getJSONArray("earnings").getJSONObject(0).getDouble("actualEPS");
```

But, why? Your attribute earnings returns an JSONArray (Which means that you have multiple rows with indizes). So, instead of just requesting "earnings" as a JSONObject, you should rather use it as a JSONArray and then extract the first row (= `.getJSONObject(0)`). After extracting the first row you can actually use your double-Value.

I hope this works :)

---

**2nd Edit:** 
Change that ..

> while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
>
> ```
> System.out.println(inputLine); } // end while
> ```

to:

> while ((inputLine += in.readLine()) != null) {
>
> ```
> System.out.println(inputLine); } // end while
> ```

Your while loop keeps iterating **until** `.readLine()` returns **null**. 
As null is the last iteration, you have only null in your variable.

As suggested you can solve that by simply changing the **= to +=**.

I hope we got it now. :)

Comment: I get the JSON from a web page using an HTTP request, is that what you're asking? I'm completely new to JSON. The files will typically be less than 10kb, would you still recommend JsonReader? Not all files will come across with multiple instances of the data I'm looking to parse, in fact it should only be one. Typically I'll be looking to parse out a specific and unique piece of data that will be a String or double.

Comment: If they are less than 10kb then JSONObject is completely fine!

Comment: Oh sorry I have overseen the actual error! I edited my post!

Comment: The JSONArray is a big help, didn't see the difference until you pointed it out. I am still getting a null pointer exception with your suggestion however. I tried the code above in my edit with the same result, NULL pointer exception. Any other ideas?

Comment: What's your output as suggested in my first answer?
System.out.println("My json: "+inputLine); //TODO: What is your output here?

Comment: inputLine is Null at that point? Why would that be? I declared the String outside of the while loop but it appears that after the while loop is done executing, inputLine is Null.

Comment: Oh sorry, I have overseen another thing ^^.
I edited my answer again.